# Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/file.php from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:1234 (ECONNREFUSED)

Tags: angular

I was configuring a proxy for my API calls. My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "intro2angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxyconfig.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

My proxyconfig.json file:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:1234",
        "secure": false,
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
```

while running `npm start` this error occurs in the terminal:

```
Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/file.php from localhost:4200 to http://localhost:1234 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors).
```

**Browser console says:**

```
GET http://localhost:4200/api/file.php 404 (Not Found).
ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/file.php", ok: false, …}
```

Comment: take help here https://medium.com/better-programming/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d

Comment: Can you hit `http://localhost:1234/api/file.php` in postman and get `200` response ?

Answer (score 0):

Put file.php inside a folder name "api" and this issue will be fixed.